# Fetching data from browser console

Tags: html, reactjs, browser, console

Is there any way to get the information (like:co-ordinates of image) from browser console?

Comment: Did my solution solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the getBoundingClientRect() method.
I choose to print it on the page but you could of course have it printed to console.

```js
    var myPlace = document.getElementById("my-place");
    var img = document.getElementById("image");
    var clientRect = img.getBoundingClientRect();
    var posLeft = clientRect.left;
    var posTop = clientRect.top;
    myPlace.innerHTML = `top: ${posLeft} left: ${posTop}`
```

```css
    .container {
        height: 100vh;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
    }
```

```html
 <div class="container">
            <img id="image" src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/800x400" alt="">
            <div id="my-place"></div>
</div>
```